# Can I force my java program to specifically execute using the jdk instead of the jre?

Tags: java

I've been looking around for an answer to this but haven't had much luck.

I've been working on a game in java that uses the javax.util.JavaCompiler class. I've discovered that this does not work with the JRE as I'll get a Null Pointer exception when I call the compiler run method (I'm assuming they simply don't ship a compiler with the JRE which is totally understandable).

My problem now is that my game inherently is dependent on the JDK. Is it possible to force my game to somehow search for the system environment variables and rather execute itself using the jdk?

I've tried using a separate launcher that then searches for the jdk and executes the game through that but that feels messy and I'm concerned there could be factors I'm missing.

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to bundle an OpenJDK with your game? Then you could completely control the execution environment and be certain that a compiler is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution to the problem. Thank you to everyone who said I should package my game with a compiler. I found [this](https://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2008/07/16/using-eclipse-compiler-to-create-dynamic-java-objects-2/) post where the author describes rather using the eclipse compiler. Apparently javax.tools.JavaCompiler is just a common interface provided, I really should learnt the API in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, but it would make your application slow to start up to go an exhaustive search.  AFAIK, there is no supported way to do this.

It is up to the user to choose how he / she runs a Java application.  Doing clever things like searching for a JDK installation is potentially dangerous.  (You could end up choosing an old insecure JDK that the user doesn't know about, or that they forgot to uninstall.  That could open up the user to security breaches, etcetera.)

I would advise limiting yourself to a friendly message to the user explaining that they need to install and/or use a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Check for the existence of that class during startup of your application; and if not found give your user a clear error message that he needs to run with a JDK (you would also specify that somehow as "prerequesites" on the site where people download your application).
2. Step back and carefully analyse which classes exactly your solution depends upon. And then you either repackage exactly those classes; or maybe you simply ship the corresponding JAR file with your application.

You see, asking your users to install a JDK is a **big** burden for them. Even when you are talking about some "inter-company" product where people have to use it ... few people are willing to install a JDK. And you absolutely should not expect that many users have a JDK installed.

On the other hand, when you consider re-packaging that stuff; you also have to look into the legal aspects; you don't want to violate any licence rules by simply handing out JDK related JARs to your customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a try/catch block for the NPE around your use of the compiler API, and, in the event of the error, inform the user in no uncertain terms of the requirement.

Or, you can use asm or some other code generator package to avoid the need for the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run your app with JDK. You can still run it with JRE. All you need to do is to make sure that a jar (from JDK or from anywhere else) that contains needed classes for your app is in your classpath. You can achieve it by including needed JAR(s) into your installation or by including the path to needed jars in your classpath parameter (-cp) when you run your app. If you want your app to run on computer where only JRE is installed you will have to include needed JAR(s) into your installation. think of it as any other third party library that you use and thus you have to package those libraries JARs into your application JAR/WAR